# keeping track of certain related field changes

Tags: mysql, data-versioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save history editable data RDBMS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28195/save-history-editable-data-rdbms)

I am totally new to databases and MySQL. I am working on a project in which I have a few related fields such as question and multiple choice asnwers. The value of those fields changes from time to time as data gathers.

Now my question is: how can I track those changes so that at any given time I am able to display the correct combination of the data? Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure your teacher wouldn't mind if you just copied this guy's homework assignment...   http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28195/save-history-editable-data-rdbms/28226#comment48483_28226

Comment: If you feel the marked duplicate does not adequately address your question, please either open a new question with more specifics (to differentiate it from the existing dupe) or edit this one and flag it for moderator attention.